# Can't open URL from a docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm having trouble with navigating to Google Authentication page from a docker container. The app is made using the asp.net Core 2.0 and it's purpose is to show upcoming events retrieved from Google Calendar API, and also to create events if needed.

The app works as expected when it's not running from a docker container, 
Authorization Code request URL is generated and based on the environment (Windows, Linux or OSX) the app tries to open the URL with Process.start() inside OpenBrowser method.

```
private bool OpenBrowser(string url)
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            url = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(url, @"(\\*)" + "\"", @"$1$1\" + "\"");
            url = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(url, @"(\\+)$", @"$1$1");
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start \"\" \"{url}\"") { CreateNoWindow = true });
            return true;
        }
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
            return true;
        }
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
        {
            Process.Start("open", url);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When the browser is successfully opened, the user needs to enter his Google Account credentials and sign in to receive the authorization code used for creating token.

```
public async Task<AuthorizationCodeResponseUrl> ReceiveCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl url, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
    {
        var authorizationUrl = url.Build().AbsoluteUri;
        using (var listener = StartListener())
        {
            bool browserOpenOk;
            try
            {
                browserOpenOk = OpenBrowser(authorizationUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Error(e, "Failed to launch browser with \"{0}\" for authorization", authorizationUrl);
                throw new NotSupportedException(String.Format("Failed to launch browser with \"{0}\" for authorization. See inner exception for details.", authorizationUrl, e));
            }
            var ret = await GetResponseFromListener(listener, taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            s_receivedCallback = true;

            return ret;
        }
    }
```

My guess is that the linux docker container doesn't have the necessary tool to open the URL and that's what's causing the issue. My question is, can somebody tell me how can I forward the URL to open on the host and not inside the container, or how can I get the token without trying to open url from the docker container?

Google by default uses that way of authenticating users (by opening url with Process.start), and also opens random port to listen for authentication response code, so I had to create my own class which implements ICodeReceiver, because docker requires exact ports to be specified before running an image inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem writing a python script and packing it into a docker image.
The only solution I found was to add the following line to the arguments `noauth_local_webserver = True`.

This is the sample code in python:

```
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('.client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    args = tools.argparser.parse_args()
    args.noauth_local_webserver = True
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, args)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
else:
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
```

With that option it prints an URL that you can copy into any web browser and after the authentication it generates a code that you need to copy into the terminal.