# Browser start from Docker

Tags: docker, google-oauth

I have a python script running from Docker container. This script requires Google authorization procedure to work with API. How to trigger browser start in container to go to authorization page and pass it?

I am working with Docker Toolbox. 
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302
docker-compose version 1.20.1, build 5d8c71b2

```
$ docker run -it  -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY docker_script
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.2) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
13:36:16.09: script service v1.14 b1
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py:255: UserWarning: Cannot access /app/.credentials/google-drive-credentials.json: No such file or directory
  warnings.warn(_MISSING_FILE_MESSAGE.format(filename))

Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=285287383820-5jgb7eskc4lno8imi7sg88bbi56hilqe.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.g
oogleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&response_type=code

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

Comment: A design goal of Docker is to make this difficult.  You might read for instance the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org): there are straightforward ways to package up Python applications to be runnable that don't need the isolation that Docker provides (and that you don't want here).

Comment: If i add google-drive-credentials.json (this file is created automatically after authorization procedure) file to .credentials directory in a project and after that build and run container everything starts good. But i need to share my application with other Google users.

Comment: More details on your environment required to answer. First, don't think about launching a web browser inside a container. Design idea: consider having the user authorize with Google Drive from their desktop. Then pass the credentials (Access Token and Refresh Token) as environment variables when you start the container. This will require you to write some code that runs in the user's browser, but this is easy to do.

Comment: Keep security first in your design. Handing out credentials in a JSON file is a VERY bad idea. Usually, when you save OAuth credentials, they timeout after 3600 seconds. Verify what is being saved.

Comment: Thank you.
Bu to be honest i don't fully understand how to do it. 
I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137948/cant-open-url-from-a-docker-container 
I have tried but again: if i use browser on host entering that URL and accept credentials, browser returns me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and i can't accept user from container.

Answer (score 0):

Today i have managed to pass Google authorization from Docker container.
I am using this construction:

```
def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')
    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        flags=tools.argparser.parse_args()
        flags.noauth_local_webserver=True
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
#    else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
#        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)

    return credentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Tidsreg files searching script v1.14'
credentials = get_credentials()                                                
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
drive_service_v3 = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
```

Docker runs container and there is a message in console to enter pass phrase from Google to get .json with credentials. And it works. Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: But now i have another question related to same issue. I have to run browser to open pages from python script. What is the best way to do it? To run separate browser from container or to trigger browser on host machine? What is the proper way to do it?
I use webbrowser.open(arg) construction in python script to open web pages.